# Iterate through a ruby hash and select a regex value

Tags: ruby, regex, hash, iterator

Hi I ran across something unexpected and can't find an answer anywhere..

I have a hash:

```
hash = {:thiskey => /value/, :anotherkey => /anothervalue/}
```

When I iterate over the hash like this:

```
hash.each do |key, value| 
   puts key
   puts value
end
```

If the value is regex /calendar/ .... the iterator produces:

```
>>> thiskey
>>>(?-mix:calendar)
```

Any thoughts on why this is?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Ruby 1.9.3-p194, could you be more specific about your Ruby version and interpreter?

Comment: Never mind, @sean seems to have nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?-mix:calendar)` is the string representation of the regular expression when using ruby.

```
>> a = /test(er)/
=> /test(er)/
>> print a.source
test(er)=> nil
>> print a
(?-mix:test(er))=> nil
>>
```

Comment: Oh okay, would you know offhand how to change it back to a regex inside the iter?

Comment: `print reg.source` I believe. It will print in your case `calendar` as that is the regular expression you wanted.

Comment: Actually it is a regular expression in side of the hash. Regular expressions are objects in ruby and using the /'s to create one creates the object itself and puts it into the hash. So you could do:

    re = hash[:thiskey]

Then use the re object to perform your checks.

Comment: Thanks your input has been super helpful! Using the regxp.source is what I needed, your second suggestion is also good to remember.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?-mix:...)
```

means "for this part of the regex, dotall mode, case-insensitive mode and verbose mode are switched off" (which is the default). The representation is just making that explicit.